# Regex: Select and replace empty lines/empty spaces between two strings on paragraph

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have this html paragraph. You see that between starting tag and the text there are some empty lines/empty spaces. I must delete them.

```
<p class="gaga">


Otra característica de este arte donde la materia es tan poco importante.</p>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<p class="gaga">Otra característica de este arte donde la materia es tan poco importante.</p>
```

I don't know why my regex doesn't make the replacement:

FIND: `(?s)(<p class="gaga">\s+)([\s\S]*?)(\w)`

REPLACE BY: `\1\3`

Answer (score 0):

FIND: `(<p class="gaga">)[\r\n]+`

REPLACE BY: `\1`

**OR**

FIND: `(<p class="gaga">)(.*?\s+)(\w+)`

REPLACE BY: `\1\3`